# is there a way to show a count(*) that is greater than a number in the column?

Tags: count

this is what I tried but I'm sure it's wrong.

```
SELECT count(12), genre
    , MIN(cost) AS Low
    , MAX(cost) AS High
    , AVG(cost) AS Average 
FROM movies
where YR > '1990'
GROUP BY genre
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve here.  Just a column that contains 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my impression of the query you were making

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(12),
    genre,
    MIN(cost) AS Low,
    MAX(cost) AS High,
    AVG(cost) AS Average
FROM movies
WHERE YR > '1990'
GROUP BY genre
```

I am not sure what it is you are trying find. Are you are trying to get all the genres that have more than 12 movies between 1990 and the present?

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS c,
    genre,
    MIN(cost) AS Low,
    MAX(cost) AS High,
    AVG(cost) AS Average
FROM movies
WHERE YR > '1990'
GROUP BY genre
HAVING c > 12
```

Comment: You're going to have to change 

`WHERE YR > '1990'
    AND c > 12
GROUP BY genre`

to 

`WHERE YR > '1990'
GROUP BY genre
HAVING c > 12`. This is because WHERE filters are processed before aggregates (e.g. COUNT) are processed, and HAVING after.

Comment: you are correct on what I'm looking for but when I put it through it gives an error     {AND c > 12
        *

ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00904: "C": invalid identifier} 
Here's what I ended up doing

SELECT count(*), genre
    , MIN(cost) AS Low
    , MAX(cost) AS High
    , AVG(cost) AS Average 

FROM movies
where YR > '1990'
having count(*) >= 12
GROUP BY genre